# writing rake that checks model and database then updates another model

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to figure out how to write a rake task that would take the model Subscription and check each column in each row, in the DB. Any row with column date that's false, it updates the User model attribute with something. So far I've got:

```
task :check_subscription => :environment do

@subscription = Subscription.find(:all)
for_each @subscription do |sub|
    Date.today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') == sub.expiry_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
end
if false
    User.subscription.user_id.update_attributed(:plan_id => '200')
end
end
```

Not really working, I'm sure I'm not doing this right.

1. I've got two models named Subscription.rb and User.rb
2. Subscription in DB has a column named expiry_date
3. User has a column plan_id that should be updated to '200' if their Subscription is false (expired).
4. Subscription has column user_id and Subscription model has `belongs_to User`.

Comment: What do you mean "not really working"?  Show the log, please.

Comment: I don't think `for_each` is in standard Ruby. Also in `Date.today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') == sub.expiry_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` why are you comparing today's date with the expiry date but doing nothing with the result? and the `if false` block will never execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
task :check_subscription => :environment do
   # Select expired subscriptions
   expired_subscriptions = Subscription.where("expiry_date < ?", Time.now.beginning_of_day)
   # Select user ids of all expired subscriptions.
   expired_subscription_user_ids = expired_subscriptions.pluck(:user_id)
   # Update all users with id = expired_subscription_user_ids so that their plan_id is 200
   User.update_all({:plan_id => '200'}, {:id => expired_subscription_user_ids})

   # Delete the expired subscriptions
   expired_subscriptions.delete
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your tip too, actually yours didn't give an error other then the NOW() not being an SQL but with little modification I came up with something like this;

Comment: `# Select user ids of all subscriptions where the expiry date is before the current time.
    expired_subscription_user_ids = Subscription.where("expiry_date < ?", Time.now.beginning_of_day).pluck(:user_id)
    # Update all users with id = expired_subscription_user_ids so that their plan_id is 200
    User.update_all({:plan_id => ''}, {:id => expired_subscription_user_ids})`

Comment: is there a way to tell it to delete the subscription after the 'User.update_all' is performed ?

Comment: just redid the `Subscription.where("expiry_date < ?", Time.now.beginning_of_day)` to remove the ones that expired.

Comment: I updated it to delete expired subscriptions after updating the user plan_ids.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this with update_all in a single statement:

```
User.joins(:subscriptions).where("subscriptions.expiry_date < ?", Time.now.beginning_of_day).update_all("users.plan_id = 200")
```

Couple of other ideas / thoughts:

1. You could also just execute a plain SQL update statement
2. If this is a one-time conversion, this should probably go in a migration instead of a standalone rake task
3. If this is a recurring thing, you'll need to include some sort of scheduling component that can call the task.

Comment: hey thanks for the tip. Yes this will be a recurring thing and the rake will pretty much run each day once. I'll fiddle around with your code to see if it fits in. Thanks again for helping me find a starting point

Comment: any idea why I'm getting a `SQLite3::SQLException: near ".": syntax error: `